# Semaphore in C Linux doesn't work properly for file operations

Tags: c, linux, file-io, semaphore

I wrote quite simple program that use semaphore: I create semaphore, fork the process several times; in every child process I generate kind of unique string, open file and than in infinite cycle I wait for semaphore, write to output file "unique string" char by char and release semaphore for another process.

But... it doesn't work properly somehow. And I want to know why and how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
/* test.c */
// gcc test.c -o test -lpthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define SEMAPHORE_NAME      "write_sync_sem"


void child_process_routine(sem_t **semaphore);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /*  
        Create semaphore
    */
    sem_t *semaphore = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    if (semaphore == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        perror("Failed to create semaphore");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid)
        {
            case -1:
                perror("Failed to fork process.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

            case 0:
                child_process_routine(&semaphore);
            break;

            default:
                printf("i = %d\n", i);
            break;

        }
    }

    getchar();

    sem_close(semaphore);

    return 0;
}

void child_process_routine(sem_t **semaphore)
{
    time_t tm;
    srand((unsigned)time(&tm) + getpid());

    int unique_number = rand();
    char unique_str[50] = {0};
    sprintf(unique_str, "such string wow very unique %d-%d\n", (int)tm, unique_number);

    int fd = open("output", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to open output file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        if (sem_wait(*semaphore) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error waiting for semaphore");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        char *pCh = unique_str;
        while (*pCh != '\0')
        {
            if (write(fd, pCh, sizeof(char)) == -1)
            {
                perror("Error writing to output file");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            pCh++;
        }


        if (sem_post(*semaphore) == -1)
        {
            perror("Error releasing semaphore");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

Expected output:

```
such string wow very unique 1425893996-318951960
such string wow very unique 1425893996-318951960
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 1425893996-1232743880
...
```

But got:

```
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 1425893996-926144838
such string wow very unique 14258939such string wow very unique 1425893996-1232743880
such string wow very unique 1425893996-1232743880
such string wow very unique 1425893996-1232743880
such string wow very unique 1425893996-123274388such string wow very unique 1425893996-624961104
such string wow very unique 1425893996-624961104
such string wow very unique 1425such string wow very unique 1425893996-18011055
such string wow very unique 1425893996-18011055
such string wow very unique 1425893996-18011055
such string wow very unique 1425893996-18011055
such string wow very unique 1425893996-18011055
```

Comment: What is the issue? "...doen't work properly" is not helping us to resolve Your issue!

Comment: @WedaPashi I gave expected output and the ouput I got. This should help, I think. The issue is that second process start writing before first finish, but it should not, because I use semaphore.

Comment: This may not be a problem, but according to documentation, your semaphore name is invalid. It must start with `/`.

Comment: @nyagod: This comment here may not solve the actual issue at hands, but, however, if you want true randomness, try seeding the time before getting the random number.

Comment: `char *pCh = unique_str;` in a while loop. What are you actually trying to do? :O

Comment: @dhke oh, thank you very much. I don't know how, but adding "/" to semaphore name fixed that issue.

Comment: @nyagod On which OS is that? Because when I try without the `/` locally, I get an error straight.

Comment: @dhke Linux 3.17.6-1-ARCH #1 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

The writes are buffered. Try with O_SYNC in the open call or call fsync() after the write while loop to ensure the data is flushed to disk before the semaphore is released.

Answer (score 0):

```
the local file structure[fd] is probably not updated
across the children, as they each open'd the file separately. 

Suggest 
always opening file with 'FILE * fp = fopen( "output", "r" );  
then in the child, after getting the semaphore,
calling 'fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );'  
then going into the loop to write to the file  
after the loop ends, call 'fflush( fp );'
then releasing the semaphore

Although the parent process can eventually exit
(or abruptly exit via 'exit()')
The children never exit, 
so when the parent exits, the children become zombies.
Note: zombie processes are difficult to get rid of
short of rebooting the computer

Note: in main(), after closing the semaphore
a call to sem_unlink() needs to be performed
otherwise the semaphore continues to exist
```